# How to use Expo + Google Sign In + Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, google-signin

I found many outdated answers to this topic so I am making fresh new one.

I have Expo React Native project and GoogleSignIn (imported from expo) working together and authenticating users.

I also need to use Firebase Auth, so when user gets authenticated by GoogleSignIn, I need to auth Firebase too:

```js
const result = await GoogleSignIn.signInAsync();
const {idToken, accessToken} = result.user.auth;
const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken, accessToken);
const answer = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
```

(I take result from google auth and then try to auth user on Firebase)

But after I sign-in I am getting this error:

> firebase cred err: [Error: Invalid Idp Response: access_token audience is not for this project]

It seems Firebase need SHA1 keys but Expo not signing app while in development and while using their app. So how to get this working?